# dealing with popups in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, popup, richfaces

is there a one-size-fits-all way to deal with popups in JSF2 (I use richfaces)?

I put together a list of requirements, I came across.

I tried a lot to overcome some of the addressed flaws, but there may exist a more complete and sophisticated example or best-practice to implement a popup in JSF.

the requirement list:

(I) the popups shall be attachted to for example a commandButton inside a dynamic list of items (a datatable or rich:tree); the item must be later be identifiable inside popup logic

(II) some logic (initialization) must be executed when popup opens

(IIIa) some logic when popup is dismissed (using a commandButton inside the popup). (IIIb) a callback action (of the calling backing bean) shall be called. (IIIc) result value should be passed to caller.

(IV) parameters need to be passed from caller to popup

(V) Can I have a (reusable) managed bean that encapsulates the popup logic? How to reference this bean from other beans? Which scope should I use?

(VI) can i avoid, that popup exists physically in DOM tree before it is shown - preventing it from being rendered/evaluated all the time

I am looking forward to your input/ideas.

regards

Comment: All this is basically covered in [RichFaces Editable DataTable example on showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=dataTableEdit). For the *reusable* managed bean, I won't really take that much into account (at least that is the same popup with the same info among different views), but still I would have the managed bean as `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: To avoid the popup existing physically in DOM, set `rendered="#{someBean.showPopup}"` that evaluates to `false` and wrap it with an `<h:panelGroup>` or another `UIContainer` component, then render this component via an ajax call that will update `someBean.showPopup` to `true`. Since all this is a lot of work to do and adds lot of maintenance problems, I would suggest to not worrying about having some HTML in the DOM that user won't notice.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for your response. but how can you avoid that getters inside the popup are called with maybe unintialized data, if you render it in the DOM? I often see code, cluttered with __if(items!=null) return items; else return EMPTY;__ - btw the datatable showcase looks very promising ! thanks

Comment: For last comment, provide properties that won't be empty. Make your code as cleaner as possible.